# Group by and row wise custom arrange in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following table with more than 10k+ rows:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(col1 = c('A','A','A','A', 'B','B','B','B', 'C','C','C','C'),
                  col2 = c('flower','pet','bird','tree','flower','pet','bird','tree','flower','pet','bird','tree'),
                  col3 = sample(0:25, 12, replace = TRUE))

   col1   col2 col3
1     A flower   14
2     A    pet   18
3     A   bird   13
4     A   tree    2
5     B flower    9
6     B    pet   17
7     B   bird   21
8     B   tree   10
9     C flower    4
10    C    pet   19
11    C   bird   13
12    C   tree   21
```

I want to arrange each row by grouping by `col1` and then arranging in order as `pet`, `tree`,`bird`,`flower` from `col2` and then keep only single occurrence of values in `col1`.

Sample desired data frame:

```
   col1   col2 col3
1     A    pet   18
2         tree    2
3         bird   13
4       flower   14
5     B    pet   17
6         tree   10
7         bird   21
8       flower    9
9     C    pet   19
10        tree   21
11        bird   13
12      flower    4
```

I could not find how to arrange the rows as I have mentioned above.
How to do achieve this?

Comment: With what would you like to replace the col1 value? With Null or NA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base R`, we can do with `order` on the 'col1' and the `factor` converted 'col2' with `levels` specified in custom order, then use `duplicated` to replace the duplicate elements in 'col1' to `""`

```
df1 <-  df[order(df$col1, factor(df$col2, 
     levels = c('pet', 'tree', 'bird', 'flower'))),]
row.names(df1) <- NULL
df1$col1[duplicated(df1$col1)] <- ""
```

-output

```
df1
#   col1   col2 col3
#1     A    pet   18
#2         tree    2
#3         bird   13
#4       flower   14
#5     B    pet   17
#6         tree   10
#7         bird   21
#8       flower    9
#9     C    pet   19
#10        tree   21
#11        bird   13
#12      flower    4
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is a good idea to get rid of the values, because a loss of information. But this is getting rid of duplicates:

```
df %>% arrange(col1) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(col1), funs(replace(., duplicated(.), "")))
```

Comment: I know that is not a good idea. but I need that output for shiny. :/

Comment: Alright, then it's understandable. I was just worried about the data structure, but if it is like this it makes perfectly sense :)

Comment: Thanks, man! Your answer worked. But akrun has posted the whole answer. Hence Selecting his answer. Thanks!